# How is a barcode found inside an image?

Tags: image-processing, qr-code, barcode, image-recognition

I've been watching some videos about face detection (Viola Jones Algorithm) and understood its principle. 
But was wondering how simpler subjects can be found. For example a barcode in an image. I can't immagine the Viola Jones Alg. to work for this, as it would produce easily wrogn results. (assumption..)

How can a simple shape like a qr-code or a barcode be found and locate its angle/outer box within an image, without detecting a simple textbox as a barcode?

NOTE: I'm not searching for a library that does this, or some code. I would just like to understand the mechanics behind this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single answer, this is symbol-dependent.

A QR code is deemed to be located by its "finder patterns", consisting of the filled squares surrounded by another square at three corners. You can find these by binarization, connected components analysis and containment tests. From the three corners, you can guess the outline.

Barcodes can be found by detecting the bars and checking their spatial relations, or by drawing profiles across the image and finding characteristic patterns in the sequence of edges crossed. Finding the exact bounding box can be a little challenging.

Comment: thank you! QR-Code is clear, thank you. could you elaborate a bit on the barcode part? how is it found if it is angled or rotated? thank you

Comment: @sharkyenergy: you can estimate the global rotation of the bars and "unrotate", or draw profiles in various directions.